# Rewriting $\sin(x+\frac {\pi} {6})\cos(x)$ as $\frac {1} {4}(2\sin(2x+\frac {\pi} {6})+1)$

Tags: trigonometry

If I have a trigonometric expression like 
$$\sin(x+\frac {\pi} {6})\cos(x)$$
what are the steps to simplify it to the following?
$$\frac {1} {4}(2\sin(2x+\frac {\pi} {6})+1)$$

Comment: Let $x=\pi/6$. The first expression evaluates to $2\sin(\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}$, the second to $(2\sin(\pi/2)+1)/4=3/4$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\sin(a+b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)+\sin(b)\cos(a)$ and $\sin(a-b)=\sin(a)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\cos(a)$ you get

$$\sin(a)\cos(b)=\frac12(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b))$$

Hence

$$\sin(x+\pi/6)\cos(x)=\frac12(\sin(2x+\pi/6)+\sin(\pi/6))$$

And since $\sin(\pi/6)=1/2$,

$$\sin(x+\pi/6)\cos(x)=\frac12(\sin(2x+\pi/6)+\frac12)=\frac14(2\sin(2x+\pi/6)+1)$$